# Android Studio and Library Projects

Tags: android, git, maven, android-studio, gradle

I'm new to Gradle, Android Studio and also to Maven repos. Here is what I want to do:

I wrote a test app, say 'MainApp', and a library project, say 'LibProject' separately in Android Studio. Both have their own git repo. When I import the LibProject as a module in my MainApp, Android Studio creates a copy of it in my project root folder. When I now push changes to my LibProject, I have to import the LibProject again to get all the changes. I also tried to checkout the LibProject to that location so Android Studio doesn't need to copy it there but it didn't build...

Isn't there a way to either

- tell Android Studio to use my 'original' LibProject that has version control instead of copying it and so removing my version control OR
- tell Android Studio to fetch the LibProject from github?

I have heard from maven repos where Android Studio can fetch projects from. Could this be the solution i'm looking for or is there any other way.

It would be nice to get some help from you guys.